# Does defining relationships in models using sequilizejs partially or completely remove the need for using include parameter?

Tags: node.js, database, sequelize.js

What is the advantage of defining relationships in sequilizejs on a given modal , is it just for the purpose of more succinct queries ? I do see an example such as (Found [**HERE**](https://sequelize.org/v3/api/associations/)) :-

```
User.hasMany(Picture)
User.belongsTo(Picture, { as: 'ProfilePicture', constraints: false })

user.getPictures() // gets you all pictures
user.getProfilePicture() // gets you only the profile picture

User.findAll({
  where: ...,
  include: [
    { model: Picture }, // load all pictures
    { model: Picture, as: 'ProfilePicture' }, // load the profile picture. Notice that the spelling must be the exact same as the one in the association
  ]
})
```

Does having a relationship defined avaoid the usage of too many queries with the `include` param ? I.E. does the below :-

```
user.getPictures() // gets you all pictures
user.getProfilePicture() // gets you only the profile picture
```

Do away with the more verbose :-

```
User.findAll({
      where: ...,
      include: [
        { model: Picture }, // load all pictures
        { model: Picture, as: 'ProfilePicture' }, // load the profile picture. Notice that the spelling must be the exact same as the one in the association
      ]
    })
```

I am using sequilizejs in an already existing project so the models were not created by me and hence an trying to understand the advantage of having relationships such as `belongsTo` and `hasOne` being defined in a model. Would appreciate any insight into the same.

**P.S.** I do see a more detailed documentation [**HERE**](https://sequelize.org/v3/docs/associations/)

Also , as a secondary question what are the other advantages of using relationships in a db ?

Answer (score 1):

Defining the relationships *is* actually required to be able to use `include` in the queries.

By using `include`, Sequelize will create a `JOIN` query, so you can get data from multiple collections which are linked by relationships without the need of a second query.

When using `belongsTo`, `hasOne`, `hasMany` etc. these methods are creating aditional columns in the table to create the relationships between the tables.